# Access Denied Even If login through site collection admin

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, user-profile-service

One site ,two site collection admin

- contoso\admin1
- contoso\admin2

Both have multiple group rights(full,contribute,etc..),
But while I login with admin2 permission denied error

**"You are currently signed in as:  Contoso\admin2
Sign in as a different user 
"**

Another thing is **admin1 is only user can access the site**,other user denied to use this site

**Tried:**

- I checked Event log but, not any error regarding that
- I tried to remove and reassign permission for site but it not works
  for me
- User Profile service is started

Comment: Can Admin2 get to other site collections. Check the Web Application user policy setting. Ensure the rules there are correct. The user profile service has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: Admin2 have Site collection admin rights in another site,but in them also Permission denied, Means particular one user(asmin2) have denied in all site collection @MatthewMcDermott

Comment: Check the Web Application user policy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restoring the site from a different web application/farm recently?

One of the things I would try is to change the site collection administrator from the central administration or may be using the account admin, which is already working and try to give the access to admin2 again. Let me know what error you get.

Comment: NO, Not restoring from different web app. But update DLL of this site ,will it takes affect the permission of site? @nisarg

Comment: I don't think it would, but which DLL have you changed?

Comment: It's web application DLL not any default DLL @Nisarg